# Tizen SDK CSS ID Not Being Rendered

Tags: css, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am using the Tizen 2.3.1 SDK for wearables and have run into an issue where no matter what I do to the style.css file, adding any new ids simply refuses to work.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

#str_day {
    position: absolute;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 10px;
    color: #6587ac;
}

#box {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

.canvas {
    background: #000;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This is my code. I am trying to add the `str_day` id however it doesn't show up when I run the package through the emulator.  The rest of the css (the canvas element, mainly) works fine, but `str_day` just doesn't show up.  I tried specifying the `z-index` and `opacity` in case some weird issue was occuring but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

This is my full code on github.

https://github.com/JoyfulOwl/RadialWatch/commit/86d096710c7187b6b3679e02416548e18a3e986e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of improper CSS layout str_day is rendered/painted outside the viewport of your watchface because of which its not visible.

I think better would be to use canvas **fillText** command to print the date on canvas.

Try below example.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font="30px Comic Sans MS";
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fillText(str_Day, mCenterX, mCenterY); // mCenterX & mCenterY are the position where text has to be shown.
```

Comment: I honestly had no idea there was a filltext command!  Thank you, I'll try this as soon as I can get back to my usable computer.